# Combine word to array of words

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to combine one word to a list of multiple words and ended up with the following in lodash:

```js
_.zipWith(
  _.times(3, _.constant("FOO")),
  ["BAR", "BAZ", "QUX"],
  (a, b) => a + b
);
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution in lodash to this? What I don't like is the portion with `_.times(3, _.constant("FOO")`, because I need to get the length of the array first.

Comment: The below solution is correct i.m.o. don't see why you would need lodash for something that can be done with a simple mapping function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you even use lodash for that? It's really simple.

```
const word = 'FOO';
const list = ['BAR', 'BAZ', 'QUX'];
const result = list.map(item => word + item);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why are you using lodash but if you only wanted to do through lodash here is the example

```js
console.log(_.map(["BAR", "BAZ", "QUX"],(x)=>`FOO${x}`))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

But you can easily achieve the same through simple javascript follow following example

```js
console.log(["BAR", "BAZ", "QUX"].map((x)=>`FOO${x}`))
```